# How to Query Kafka table periodically?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

1. I have use case where there are events comming from a topic pattern (`myTopic-cusId`). I have set up a kafka stream listener which listen to the incoming events from these topics.
2. What I have done so far is build a stream from the topic and created a Ktable which keeps the running sum and averages of various customer metrics.
3. Now I want to filter the stream based on the values and condition of Ktable but I want the filtering to be happening periodically (but I want to wait for this filter to happen at the starting of building the stream (to make sure that Ktable has some useful info to check the conditions)) (`Lets says wait for first 30 secs to start the filtering from the first event and after that query the state store every 20 secs until all the events are processed.`)

Is there any way I could achieve this or any design pattern that would solve this use case?

Comment: You cannot "delay" a filter... Why cant you `.filter()` the stream before creating the table?

Comment: I want to filter it againts the values in Ktable. But in the intial processing of the stream the Ktable would not have very meaninful averages/sums of the events

Comment: KTables are just key-value pairs and with key lookups or scans. There is no server-side filtering you can do after you have the table/state-store. You would have to query everything, then filter client side like a regular Java collection. Then put that in a loop if you want it to be periodic